# MYSQL|Inserting values into SET datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, set

Could anyone tell me how to insert data into SET column in SQL and modify it

Could changing of the value be like this?

```
 UPDATE table SET set_column='a',' b',' c'
```

and inserting

```
INSERT INTO table(int_column,set_column) 
VALUES (126,('a','b'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how you do sets: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html

```
INSERT ... VALUES (intval, 'set,values,here')
                           ^---^------^----^
```

Note that the set value is basically just a CSV string. One single string value, with multiple values separated by a comma inside that string.

Answer (score 3):

You have everything in [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)

```
UPDATE table SET set_column='a,b,c'

INSERT INTO table(int_column,set_column) 
VALUES (126, 'a,b')
```